How to host pwa-kit on AWS?
Currently, I am trying to host the PWA Kit on AWS instead of the Managed Runtime as part of a POC. While I was able to set up the PWA Kit, I encountered an issue with the proxy configuration.
Here's the error I get when trying to authorize from Salesforce:

Error: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host:
pwa-kit-poc.mulrajdev.com is not in the cert's altnames:
DNS:ssl1077358.cloudflaressl.com,
DNS:*.commerce-api-eu.api.commercecloud.salesforce.com,
DNS:commerce-api-eu.api.commercecloud.salesforce.com

Here are the details:
The pwa-kit app internally uses AWS lambda with S3 and Cloudfront.
Custom-hosted PWA Kit application: https://pwa-kit-poc.mulrajdev.com/
